# MATLAB candles plot: layers order

Tags: matlab, plot, candlestick-chart

I try to put a marker on a candle plot of Matlab.
But the marker is placed under the candle, and the marker can't be seen if it is too small.

I tried to use uistack to reorder the layers, but the marker is still placed behind the candle body.

```
load disney;
candle(dis_HIGH(end-20:end), dis_LOW(end-20:end), dis_CLOSE(end-20:end),...
dis_OPEN(end-20:end), 'b');
hold on;
markers = plot(2,20.4,'r^','MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerSize',15);
uistack(markers,'top');
hold off;
```

How to make the marker to be in front of the candle?
[image: marker is behind the canle body]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can circumvent this issue by doing the following:

1) Add a new transparent axes at the same position than the existing one.

2) Make its `NextPlot` property set to `add`.

3) Adjust its limits to fit with that of the axes generated by the candle plot.

So in code this looks like this:

clear all

```
clc
close all

load disney;

candle(dis_HIGH(end-20:end), dis_LOW(end-20:end), dis_CLOSE(end-20:end),...
dis_OPEN(end-20:end), 'b');
%//======================

%// Get current axes
Axes1 = gca;

%// Get the current limits
Axes1XLim = get(gca,'XLim');
Axes1YLim = get(gca,'YLim');

%// Create new axes
hold on
NewAxes = axes('Position',get(gca,'Position'),'Color','none','XTick',get(Axes1,'XTick'),'YTick',get(Axes1,'YTick'),'NextPlot','add')

%// Plot your data on new axes
m = plot(NewAxes,2,20.4,'r^','MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerSize',15);

%// Adjust its limits
xlim(Axes1XLim)
ylim(Axes1YLim)
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! My pleasure I learned something as well haha. Cheers :)